# How do I check if the list is empty recursively in lisp?

Tags: lisp

I have funtion  called:

```
(defun color ( list1 list2 list3 list4 list5 listoflist))

(defun color (list1 list2 list3 list4 list5 listoflist)                           
    (cond 
        (null list1) 'unknown )
        (list (list1, list2 list3 list4 list5 lisoflist))
        (null list2) 'unknown)
          (list (list1 list2 list3 list4 list5 listoflist)

         (null list3) 'unknown )
        (null list4) 'unknown) 
        (null list5) 'unknown )

        (T (cons (car list1) (color (cdr list1) list2)))    ; recursively tring to replace with unknow if any of the lis tis empty and print the resulte ouptput
    )
)
```

if the input is: `(color null '(3 4 5) null) '(3 5 8) null))`
it should produce `(unknown (3 4 5) unknown (3 4 5) unknown)`

Comment: Your function requires 6 arguments. The recursive call only has 1 argument. Why are you ignoring `list2` through `list5`?

Comment: I'm very fresh to lisp and I shouldn't have done that but don't know how to recursively check if the list is empty? and replace empty with anything.

Comment: Why is the last element of the result `unknown` instead of `(unknown)` like the third element?

Comment: Since the last element of the input is `(null)`, not `null`.

Comment: You don't put quotes inside a list that's already quoted. The first quote quotes the entire thing. And quotes don't appear in output, they're just part of input syntax.

Comment: What does it produce? Have you tried it?

Comment: The parentheses around balanced in your input. You have an extra `)` after the second `null`.

Comment: There's also no variable named `null` in Lisp, it's `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your `COND` syntax is not correct. The syntax of `COND` is:

```
(cond
    (condition1 result1...)
    (condition2 result2...)
    ...
)
```

Each combination of a condition and results should be in a list. You did it correctly for the `T` condition, but not for the `(null list1)` condition. It should be:

```
(cond
    ((null list1) unknown)
    (t (color (cdr listoflist)))
)
```

But your function logic is totally wrong for what you want to do.

First, the function shouldn't take multiple arguments. It should just take a single `list` argument.

Second, you need to map over the list to process each element recursively.

Third, you need to quote `unknown` to return it literally.

Fourth, in the input, an empty list should be `nil` or `()`, not `null`. That's the name of the function that tests whether a list is empty.

```
(defun color-recurse (thing)
  (cond ((null thing) 'unknown)
        ((listp thing) (mapcar #'color-recurse thing))
        (t thing)))

(defun color (&rest things)
  (color-recurse things)) 

(color nil '(3 4 5) '(nil) '(3 5 8) '(nil))
```

output:

```
(unknown (3 4 5) (unknown) (3 5 8) (unknown))
```

Comment: Thank you. But the thing is that the function has multiple parameters that accepts multiple arguments of list. And if any of those list are empty  I should replace with unknown or any empty list. So that I can loop through each list and print the elements again from each list. It probably makes sense now because I just edited the question.

Comment: I've added a wrapper function that takes the inputs as separate arguments using `&rest`. It's easier to write the recursive function with a single argument.

Comment: Thank you so much Barmar for your effort in helping me. But things is that it is homework assignment i'm trying to complete. And those parameters are requirements. And by the way the last parameters should return list that is corresponding to last list.

Comment: Your question is not very clear about all this. Please show the actual way that the function is supposed to be called.

Comment: (color '(1 (3 3) 5  nil (2 1) nil ): I think this is the way it should be called and result should be : ( 1 (3 3)  5  unknown ( 2 1) unknown). The six arguments function. And sorry for the confusion. Like I said earlier i'm still learning lisp and very new to me.

Comment: That's one argument, not six arguments. But you're missing a `)` at the end.